# What does Array and ... does here?

Tags: swift

I have this line here, I can not understand the purpose, and the sytacs.

`instances = Array(Array(instance.enumerated())[prefixItems.count...])`

1. What does `...`
2. What does `[prefixItems.count...]` when creating an `Array`?
3. How `instances` can be assigned to a type like: `[(Int, Any)]`.

this is the whole statement, it is syntactically valid:

```swift
  let instances: [(Int, Any)]
  if let prefixItems = schema["prefixItems"]?.array {
    guard instance.count > prefixItems.count else {
      return AnySequence(EmptyCollection())
    }
    instances = Array(Array(instance.enumerated())[prefixItems.count...])
  } else {
    instances = Array(instance.enumerated())
  }
```

but for some reason I need convert `Any` to `DataToValidate`, like:

```swift
  let instances: [(Int, DataToValidate)]
```

and then I got error:

> Cannot assign value of type 'Array<EnumeratedSequence<(JSONArray)>.Element>' (aka 'Array<(offset: Int, element: JSONValue)>') to type '[(Int, DataToValidate)]'

Comment: One sided range: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html#ID73

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `x...` is a one-sided range from `x` to "as far as possible", i.e., to the end of the array in case of subscripting, as done here.
2. `Array(instance.enumerated())` initializes an array from the enumerated sequence `instance`, i.e., `[(Int, Any)]`. The subscript `[prefixItems.count...]` takes the elements from that array starting from the index `prefixItems.count` and continuing to the end. The outer `Array` initializes an array of that sequence.
3. The types of everything involved above (in practice some will have more specific actual types, but they conform to these):

   - `instance` – some Sequence, but we can consider it `[Any]`
   - `instance.enumerated()` – `Sequence<(Int, Any)>`
   - `Array(instance.enumerated())` – `[(Int, Any)]`
   - `Array(instance.enumerated())[prefixItems.count...]` – `Sequence<(Int, Any>)>`
   - `Array(Array(instance.enumerated())[prefixItems.count...])` – `[(Int, Any)]`

P. S. As pointed out in comments, note that the intermediate array and subscripting is unnecessary, and the same outcome can be achieved with `Array(instance.enumerated().dropFirst(prefixItems.count))`. This also makes the `guard` unnecessary.

Comment: Worth noting that the intermediate array and slicing is roundabout. `Array(instance.enumerated().prefix(prefixItems.count))`

Comment: @Alexander Good point, that is indeed better! I was too focused on answering the specific question to notice. =)